# C++ Map with customized comparator does not work correctly

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator

Map with a customized comparator does not work as expected.

Code:

```
struct Comp {
    const bool operator()(const int x, const int y) const {
        return abs(x) < abs(y);
    }
};

map<int, int, Comp> func(vector<int>& arr) {
    map<int, int, Comp> mp;
    for (int x : arr) {
        mp[x]++;
    }
    return mp;
};

int main() {
    vector<int> arr = { 4, -2, 2, -4 };
    map<int, int, Comp> res = func(arr);

    for (auto it : res) {
        cout << it.first << " -> " << it.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-2 -> 2
4 -> 2
```

Expected:

```
-4 -> 1
-2 -> 1
2 -> 1
4 -> 1
```

Does anyone know if C++ is wrong or my expected result is wrong?

Comment: The output is correct - you made -2 equal to 2, -4 equal to 4. The expectation is wrong.

Comment: According to your comparator `-2 < 2` is `false` (since `2 < 2` is `false`) and `2 < -2` is also `false`. Since neither `2` nor `-2` is smaller than the other, they compare equal.

Comment: How is your expected output any different from a map with a default `std:less` comparator? What is your custom comparator is actually expected to accomplish, if it's to produce any kind of a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` uses the comparator to test ordering, but also to know if two keys are equal, i.e., if `comp(a,b) == false` and `comp(b,a) == false`, then it means that the 2 keys are equal and that they should be considered the same, even though the bits in memory are different.

In your case, `comp(-2,2)` and `comp(2,-2)` are both false so it considers it as a single entry. Same thing for -4 and 4. Since the two first inserted keys are 4 and -2, these are the two keys that are set in the map. And since both negative and positive keys point to the same entry, then it increments each value twice.